# Create TableView from Mutable Array

Tags: nsmutablearray, tableview

I'm pretty new to iOS development and I can't seem to find the answer to my problem: I have a ViewController containing (among other things) a TableView. This TableView is populated with items from a mutable array and what I want to do is to create a table which will be made only by 2 rows if the mutable array only has 2 entries. And also, if the table has more than (let's say) 5 entries, the TableView should have a scroll.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Make a table view height fit as 2 row or increase the height of the row ..

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty much simple. Lets say your array is chuckJokes. Just add the array as a property or member of the class so that you can use it in all methods.

Then populate the array with whatever values you need. Later follow the following methods to populate the tableview according to the array.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [chuckJokes count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chuck"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"chuck"] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text = [chuckJokes objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```